# How to load image using getResources() in Java JApplet?

Tags: java, swing, jar, embedded-resource, japplet

I'm trying to deploy a Java applet. When I run it in the Eclipse applet viewer, it loads fine (although it doesn't respond to keyboard commands- that's a question for later). After exporting it to a JAR and trying to run it in a browser, it always gives a NullPointerException on this line in one of the classes:

```
private static final ImageIcon NULL_IMAGE = new ImageIcon((new Object()).getClass().getResource("/tiles/blank.png"));
```

I tried moving the first use of this class from init() to start() with no change. Running "jar -tf applettest.jar" in the terminal window confirms that /tiles/blank.png does indeed exist in the JAR.
So what could I have missed when exporting this JAR? Should I just forget about the applet version and use JNLP?

Comment: *"Should I just forget about the applet version and use JNLP?"* - That would generally be a good idea, but might not solve the issue at hand.  As for the applet not responding to key strokes, that's a common issue with `KeyListener`, which was solved through the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Have you tried using `new ImageIcon(YourClass.class.getResource("/tiles/blank.png"));`?

Comment: Using TheClass.class seems to fix the image issue… or at least, give me a different error, this time saying it can't connect to the server DB. Regarding the key issue, I'm using key bindings, not KeyListeners. I should note that there's a standalone version which doesn't have either issue, at least when run from Eclipse. I guess I'll try making deploying it with JNLP.

Comment: Ah, well, I guess the second issue is out of context to the question, but I would suggest that this a issue with the tight security restrictions of applets, at a guess

Answer (score 0):

Move your PNG image into the same package as your class, and try this:

```
private final ImageIcon NULL_IMAGE = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blank.png"));`
```

Note that `NULL_IMAGE` becomes `private final` but not `private static final`.

Comment: *"Move your PNG image into the same package as your class, and try this:"*  Given the `/` prefix, that will only work if the class calling it is in the default package.